# Let $r$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $m$. Show that there are exactly $2^r$ integers $x$ such that $0\leq x<m$ and $x^2\equiv x\pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $r$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $m$. Show that there are exactly $2^r$ integers $x$ such that $0\leq x<m$ and $x^2\equiv x\pmod m$

Answer (score 3):

This will follow from the Chinese remainder theorem if you can show the result for a prime power $m = p^n$.

So we need to show that $x^2 = x (\bmod p^n)$ has exactly $2$ solutions. It's clear that $0$ and $1$ are solutions. These are the only ones: generally, we would have $p^n | (x^2-x) = x(x-1)$, and since $x$ and $x-1$ are coprime, either $p^n | x$ or $p^n | x-1$, that is $x \equiv 0$ or $x \equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $m$ is prime is true ($x=0,1$ are the only solutions).
If $m$ is a power of prime again true ($x=0,1$ are the only solutions).
Now use the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem).